# When mounting my HDD I get unable to mount location"

Tags: mount, 12.10

I have replaced windows 8 with ubuntu 12.10 , and after installing i can't open hdd and i get this Message `unable to mount location`

I have very important files on my hhd therefore I can't formate it. What should I do to get to my harddrive?

Comment: what did you do to "open hdd"? Did you run a mount-command, did you click on something. Did you install Ubuntu on a different drive? How is the drive connected? Please add some more information about what's going on.

Comment: @ nanne :  @ nanne: when installing ubuntu there is Different options  like " install inside windows " & " replace windows 8" & "something else" i have Chose "replace windows 8" and complet installing after that i can't open my hhd

Comment: Ok, so you did "replace windows 8". I assume you only had 1 harddisk (`c:`)? But what happens now? you are booting your computer, you see ubuntu, and then? You must be doing something to get that error. Does de boot-process show this error, do you do anything in Ubuntu to get this error? Please describe what is going on exactly. step by step. What did you do, what do you do, when do you see what. It takes some effort, but it's the only way the situation will be clear. Please don't only comment, but edit the important information in your question.

Comment: THat's helpfull, but seriously: 1. edit your question so the whole thing becomes clear. This is a Q&A site, not a forum :D  2. answer the other questions too please: who what where why are you getting this error? Add all the steps that you took as if explaining to a person on the other side of the world (probably true) that cannot see your computer... that said: if you replaced everything, you might have formatted everything, which means you might have lost your data (data-recovery might be some help though.)

Comment: ok sir, first i have 3 partition (c:) for windows 8 and (D:) & (E:) after replace windows 8 with ubuntu the hhd became one partition (320 gb) after it was ( 50gb for C:) and (133 gb for D:) and (133 gb for E:) and i try to install windows again but i found the hdd 320g and ther is no partition and i should format the hhd to install windows

Comment: Ok, this is the last time I'm going to nag you about this, because it looks like you have enough problems, but next time you should really add this kind of information in your question. That means, if you think of it later, **EDIT** your question.

Answer (score 1):

From your comments I think that you have formatted your drive before/during installing Ubuntu. The fact that reinstalling windows also asks for a format confirms this: windows cannot use the Ubuntu file-system.

This means that you should STOP adding stuff to your harddisk. No installs, nothing. If you want any chance of data-recovery, you need to start doing everything from a live-CD or a USB.

Data-recovery is hard. You formatted everything. It is next to impossible to help you with this online if you have limited knowledge yourself, but I can explain the path you can hope for.

1. there are methods of formatting that do not write something to ALL places on your harddisk, only write something in the beginning. You must hope you have this.
2. there are programs that can re-create your files if you did above thing, obviously apart from the places Ubuntu has written new files. This is quite hard, so you might want to find a professional or someone close to help you with this.
3. As said, you cannot recover files that you have written over. So everywhere you write new data, you lose some of the old data, so DON'T USE THE DISK if you really need to recover files.

Comment: ok sir but if i formatte the hdd and install windows CAN I recover my data with any recover data programs ??? and there is any advice to me and excuse me for all question and i will never ever install ubuntu again ,,,, thank you sir

Comment: Did you read my points? **DON'T FORMAT** and **DON'T ISNTALL ANYTHING** if you want to rescue anything. Bring your computer to a specialist, or consider your data lost. Please read the answer, it says so, doesn't it. I repeat, DON'T INSTALL OR FORMAT. Also: this is hardly Ubuntu's fault by the way, don't be discouraged: this could have happened by installing any new OS.

Answer (score 0):

try to run a live disk to access your data and get backup of it

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery